# Delete rows of CSV file based on the value of a column

Tags: csv, awk

Here's an example of a few lines of my CSV file:

```
movieID,actorID,actorName,ranking
1,don_rickles,Don Rickles,3
1,jack_angel,Jack Angel,6
1,jim_varney,Jim Varney,4
1,tim_allen,Tim Allen,2
1,tom_hanks,Tom Hanks,1
1,wallace_shawn,Wallace Shawn,5
```

I would like to remove all rows that have a ranking of > 4, so far I've been trying use this awk line:

```
awk -F ','  'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (($4) < 5)  print }' file.csv > file_out.csv
```

It should print all the rows with a ranking (4th column) of less than 5 to a new file. I can't tell exactly what this line actually does, but it's not what I want. can someone tell me where I've gone wrong with that line?

Comment: guess what does `<5` mean?

Comment: it should mean if the value of column 4 is less than 5.

Comment: yep , if this line worked, you change `<5` into `>4` should go, right?

Comment: @Kent wouldn't that output all lines with a value of >4 into file_out.csv? in my example above, it would print `1,jack_angel,Jack Angel,6` and `1,wallace_shawn,Wallace Shawn,5` into file_out.csv

Comment: and the last line too (5>4). what do you expect then?

Comment: I want to print a list all rows with a ranking of less than 5. so the rows that I expect to output should be: `1,tom_hanks,Tom Hanks,1`, `1,tim_allen,Tim Allen,2`, `1,don_rickles,Don Rickles,3`, `1,jim_varney,Jim Varney,4`

Comment: your codes in your question gives you the result, right? even though it could be written better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting the records, think of which ones you're going to print. I guess it's `<=4`.  In idiomatic `awk` you can write this as

```
$ awk -F, '$4<=4' file

1,don_rickles,Don Rickles,3
1,jim_varney,Jim Varney,4
1,tim_allen,Tim Allen,2
1,tom_hanks,Tom Hanks,1
```